# What department level internal accountability standards can be developed for improving problem advisors

Tags: phd, advisor

My dissertation has just been approved and I can not be more relieved. I am not relieved because of impostor syndrome or because the work load was too high. I am relieved that I never have to meaningfully interact with my advisor again unless I decide to. I can go into industry, and none of my future success requires further actions or approval from my advisor who is so prone to inaction and the inability to effectively communicate.

I am in a highly theoretical STEM field, where the individual research interests of professors are so distinct it is difficult to get good guidance from other committee members. Additionally, the barrier to entry is quite high and it is not common to complete publications in this field without heavy guidance.
During my PhD studies, I developed severe anxiety regarding meeting deadlines and the ability to control my own success. It was very frequent that meetings would be canceled at the last moment. My advisor was full of excuses, and as legitimate as they may be, did not offer sincere apologies. There are long periods where I make attempts for communication, by email, messaging, and phone call, with little or no response. There are empty promises of reading my work or doing a small task by a certain date, which are not met and when not met not addressed with an apology or request for more time, but rather a slew of excuses of being laden with administrative and personal affairs.

I have had many mental breakdowns during my PhD. These stem from politely pushing him to take action, and repeatedly being ignored or given false promises of completing said action. The inability for my polite actions to result in him taking necessary action for my success is the root of these breakdowns and anxiety. At times I have shared these ailments with my advisor, however this hasn't changed his behavior, perhaps superficially for a short amount of time, but the pattern reemerges shortly after.

I am free now, but it is my true belief that inaction and inability to effectively communicate, especially when aware of a student's declining mental health, is abusive. This realization was gradual, I perhaps only realized I felt this way 4 years in. I did not speak out because I was afraid that it would waste my years of work. Once I have degree in hand, I will no longer afraid of speaking out (I am not afraid of not having his reference, I am not confident in his ability to write a good reference in a timely manner, and I have other references.). I have talked to other students in my research group, and we all share some notion of this decline in mental health. I want my actions to help them, and I understand that these feelings may not be completely localized to this one advisor and may be a more common phenomena in academia.

I do not want to defame. My feeling is my advisor is experiencing mental health decline himself. I do think that professors, as people of power, have the responsibility to be good advisors and not directly cause mental health decline. I want to reach out to the department, but I do not know how to effectively incite change. I do not want to complain. I want to create change. First I want to create change for my former peers who are suffering the inaction of my advisor. If successful, a general method is preferred that can be applied in various departments. I want to start by inciting reform to increase the accountability of problem professors to communicate regularly and allow students to control their success to a larger degree.

I have thought about writing letters to the department chair and graduate student general advisor, and I think that is the first step. I was wondering if any of you have suggestions, or have had success creating localized reform within a department before. This will certainly not be easy, however your suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: I found your post far too long to read and I suspect others will as well. If you have a specific question, can you distill your question to that and avoid the extra story that is not relevant?

Comment: Too much rant, not enough question.

Answer (score 1):

At some universities, all PhD students have multiple advisors.  In principle, this means that if one advisor is not doing their job, other advisors will fill in the gaps.  This is not exactly accountability, but it gets close.

At some universities, all PhD advisors are required to meet certain standards.  In principle, if they fall below those standards, their ability to continue having PhD students could be revoked.  However, there is no accurate way to measure supervision quality, so this is not completely reliable.

In my experience, these are university policies, but there is no reason they could not be departmental policy.

The best form of accountability available is for students to refuse to work for advisors who do a bad job.  That's not what you asked for, but it's the best that exists.